# Angular array changes detection

Tags: angular, ngoninit, ngonchanges

I am a beginner with Angular, and i can't find proper solution for my problem.

I have a component containing table filled with list of items (each item in list is in another component), and there is third component containing filter. Filter contains multiple checkboxes and a filter button.

I send boolean array of checkboxes states from filterComponent through itemsListComponent to singleItemComponent and it works fine. My problem is changes detection. When I used NgDoCheck with differs it works always when I click at checkbox and filter button instead only filter button.

I tried NgOnChanges but it worked only once and then it didn't see any changes of values into array.

This is my SingleItemsComponent (I think you don't need others to help me solve this). Look at this and show me any example of solving this problem please.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges,ViewChild, AfterViewInit, Inject,     Input, DoCheck, KeyValueDiffer, KeyValueDiffers, SimpleChanges, SimpleChange,     ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, IterableDiffers } from     '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from     '@angular/animations';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator, MatSort,     throwToolbarMixedModesError } from '@angular/material';
import { IPOLine } from 'src/app/models/po-line';
import { POLineService } from 'src/app/services/po-line.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-po-lines-list',
  templateUrl: './po-lines-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./po-lines-list.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('collapsed', style({ height: '0px', minHeight: '0', display:     'none' })),
      state('expanded', style({ height: '*' })),
      transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4,     0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class POLinesListComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck{
  isLogged = false;
  login: string;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<IPOLine>();
  expandedElement: IPOLine;
  errorMessage: string;
  response: any;
  today = new Date(); // (1990, 0, 1);
  isLoadingList = true;

  differ: any;

  @Input() sentData: boolean[];
  _sentData = this.sentData;
  ngDoCheck(){

    var changes = this.differ.diff(this._sentData);
    if (changes){
      console.log('changes detected changes detected changes detected     changes detected changes detected ');
    }
    else
    console.log('changes not detected changes not detected changes not     detected changes not detected ');
  }


  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(
    //private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private differs: KeyValueDiffers,
    private _POLineService: POLineService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
      this.differ = differs.find({}).create();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Assign the data to the data source for the table to render
    this.login = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('login');
    this._POLineService.getUserPOLines(this.login)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.dataSource.data = data;
          },
        error => {
          this.errorMessage = <any>error;
          this.isLoadingList = false;
        }
        ,
        () => {
          // console.log('eee' + this.dataSource.data);
          this.isLoadingList = false;
          this.dataSource.data.forEach(x => x.isExpired = new     Date(x.PromisedDate) < new Date() ? true : false);
        }
      );

    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
}
```

I'm sorry for the mess in a code but I tried so many things i don't even remember what was what. Thanks for any help.

FilterComponent.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-filters',
  templateUrl: './filters.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filters.component.css']
})
export class FiltersComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() filterByClass = new EventEmitter();
  filterByTTR = false;
  filterByTBR = false;
  filters:boolean[] = [];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

log() {
  if(!this.filterByTTR)
   console.log('TTR not checked');
   else
   console.log('TTR checked');
  if (!this.filterByTBR)
   console.log('TBR not checked');
   else
   console.log('TBR checked');
   this.filters[0] = this.filterByTTR;
   this.filters[1] = this.filterByTBR;

   this.filterByClass.emit(this.filters);
}
```

Part of FilterComponent.html:

```
<mat-card-content class="col">
<mat-checkbox [checked]="filterByTTR" (change)="filterByTTR = !filterByTTR">TTR</mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox [checked]="filterByTBR" (change)="filterByTBR = !filterByTBR">TBR</mat-checkbox>
<!-- <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="filterByTBR"ref-TBR>TBR</mat-checkbox> -->
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
  <button mat-raised-button  color="primary">Clear</button>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="log()" color="primary">Apply</button>
</div>
```

PoLinesCompoenent.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule, ViewChild, Input } from 
'@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-po-lines',
  templateUrl: './po-lines.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./po-lines.component.css']
})    
export class POLinesComponent implements OnInit {
  count: boolean[];
  constructor() { }    
  ngOnInit(){}      
  displayCounter(count) {
    console.log('first value is: ' + count[0] + ' second value is: ' +     count[1]);
    this.count = count;
  }
```

PoLinesComponent.html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="side-bar col">
      <app-filters (data)='displayCounter($event)'></app-filters>
    </div>
    <div class="content col">
      <app-po-lines-list [sentData]="count"></app-po-lines-list>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to detect change when `@Input() sentData: boolean[];` from the outside changes?

Comment: Exactly, I'm trying to detect changes in the other component. Do you know what's wrong here?

Comment: Ok so basically you want to perform some action in the POLinesListComponent when `sentData` is changed via a parent component right?

Comment: That's it, I select checkboxes, click filter button, and then array with their states goes to PoLinesComponent which is a parent component of PoLinesListComponent and FilterComponent.

Comment: Got it. See my answer

Comment: In this line of PoLinesComponent.html: `<app-filters (data)='displayCounter($event)'></app-filters>`, you are handling the event using `data` but the name of the event emitter in FilterComponent.ts is `filterByClass`. So i think this line should be replaced by `<app-filters (filterByClass)='displayCounter($event)'></app-filters>` . Try doing it and see if the problem resolves.

Comment: I changed one of those names only for you to make it more clear, but forgot about another one, it's not a problem here.

Comment: Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the setter with input to detect the changes if 'sentData` input is changed by the parent. The setter function will be called everytime the input changes from outside. For example you can do something like:

```
  @Input('sentData') 
  set sentData(value:any){
     //this function will be called whenever value of input changes. the value parameter will contain the new changed 
      this._sentData=value;
      //things to perform on change go here
  }
  _sentData;
```

See this link for more details about input change detection : [Intercept @Input property change in Angular](https://medium.com/@bharat.tiwari/intercept-input-property-change-in-angular-690567eb63ec)
Hope this helps.

If the value passed in input via parent is not a primitive type then angular wont detect the changes in that object and the setter wont be called in the child i.e. `POLinesListComponent`. For fixing this issue and getting your change detected, you can use `Object.assign` function of javascript which will change the reference of `this.count` thus triggering angular change detection. 
You can do something like the following in your `displayCounter` function:

```
displayCounter(count) {
    console.log('first value is: ' + count[0] + ' second value is: ' +     count[1]);
    //if count is changed, then only trigger change.
    if(JSON.stringify(this.count)!=JSON.stringify(count))
    {

      this.count= []; 
      Object.assign(this.count, count);
    }

  }
```

I have even created a stackblitz similar to your implementation in which the change is being detected properly and the value of new count is being logged to the console everytime filter is applied. Here [Input Change Detection for Object](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-cgyjjn?file=app%2Ffilters%2Ffilters.component.html)

Comment: It's something similar i have done before and it behaves exactly the same. I followed your instructions, and added console.log to see if it reaches setter each time I filter. Unfortunately it sees changes only once at the first time.

Comment: How is the value being changed in the parent component? Is it two way binded to a control or you change it manually in a function?

Comment: In a moment I will edit my question and I add other components code.

Answer (score 1):

Angular change detection only checks if something changed by reference. In your parent component, you have to create a new array and assign it to the variable everytime a change occurs to your entries inside your array. Just think of arrays as Immutables.

Comment: I reed about Immutables, and i know it's not the best solution when there is big object to recreate, that means there must be another way to do this. Indeed I will try do that with them because this array isn't gonna be big.

Comment: There is no other way to do that. It would be way slower to check if any elements in an array changed than to just recreate it. What you could do to bypass this if performance is an issue is scheduling the change detector yourself - change the array as mucb as you want, recreate it once and then use ChangeDetectorRef to mark the component for check. Additionally, the overhead for recreating an array is usually not much.